# Different fields per taxonomy term

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities

A classified like site requires very different fields per category or taxonomy term.  For example car will need fields like milage, model etc.. while a house will have no. of bedrooms, sqr. feet etc. I am finding different ways to do this but not sure which is scalable.  I will also be using faceted search api.

First Method:
Create a generic entity with common fields and programmatically create custom entity per category which will be related using entity reference.

Second Method:
Create single entity or content type with all fields and write logic to hide and show fields per category.

Third Method
Create content type per category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the fields differ markedly, that's a case for a different content type.

e.g "Vehicle" and "House" would be two distinct content types with their own fields - much easier in the long run.

Comment: This works even if there is many (say 50+) categories? Content type for each one?

Comment: I think even the commerce-kickstart uses the same thing.